# Error while installing nodeJS mysql package on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to nodeJS,

I am trying to install mysql package of nodeJS as

```
>node

>npm install mysql
```

and also with

```
>npm install node-mysql
```

but getting error as

```
npm should be run out side of the node repl in your normal shell
```

so i run the same command in side nodeJS directory in program file

still getting error check images
[image: node shell command]
[image: node-debug.log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is indicating that the path referred to in the screenshot above (.../AppData/Roaming/npm) is not available (doesn't exist or isn't accessible by your user).

Can you make sure there is a folder `npm` at this path:

```
c:\Users\mayank.bhadauria\appdata\roaming
```

If not, please create it and then try `npm install node-mysql` again.